# GitHub Enterprise Admin Function - Add Arbitrary User to Organization

Tags: github

Is it possible in GitHub enterprise to arbitrarily add a user to an organization if you are a site administrator.  I am evaluating the software, but cannot seem to do this reliably.  A site admin who is not themselves part of an organization cannot pull up the organizations dashboard, nor see which users are part of it, although they can view and contribute to the repositories within (in a round about way).  I know that it is possible to impersonate a non-admin user, but you would have to know who already is a part of that organization to do this, which is hidden.  There has to be a better way because what if some nefarious employee and removed everyone but themselves.  The organization would effectively be orphaned.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I think I have found where all the members are, under "Members & Teams", duh. I can usurp their account and make myself an owner if needed. Seems cumbersome though.

Comment: Where can I find `Members & Teams`? I'm a site admin, yet cant add users to an organization.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want [ghe-org-admin-promote](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/admin/installation/command-line-utilities#ghe-org-admin-promote)